# Simple way to render tuples to a table in ASP.NET 2.0?

Tags: asp.net

Say I have a data structure like a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>` or similar, and I want to render this as an HTML table with row-headers as the first string key, and column headers as the second string key. Is there a built-in or other Control for this?

Comment: Alternately, I could get the data from a database in a format like "row,col,value" if that makes things easier...

Comment: I ended up building a simple control that has a 'setData(row, col, value)' method and renders to an HTML table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no built in controls that will recognize a complex data structure like that.  You'll need to do a bit of custom coding for it.

You could probably easily accomplish it with a Repeater with an ItemDataBound event handler.  Just off the top of my head, no testing:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound=" Repeater1_OnItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


protected void Repeater1_OnItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType ==
          ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var rowHeader= (e.Item.DataItem).Key;
        var columnHeaders = (e.Item.DataItem).Value;
        foreach (var header in columnHeaders)
        {
              // build string to populate table row, assign to Literal1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a control that will recognize another type of data structure that holds this style of data? like the SQL result mentioned above (row, col, value)?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You can use a gridview to recognize DataRow style of data, so if you can get your tuples into a DataTable, you can easily bind to the table and have your headers handled by the HeaderTemplate, and the row headers could be in the first column.  But there is no out-of-the-box spreadsheet style control that will parse the data like that as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested databound controls and skip the OnItemDataBoundStep, just bind the inner control with a property of the outer item that is being bound.

So for your case each item in your dictionary contains a key, and another dictionary.  So each time you bind you have access to the dictionary for that item to set as the data source for the inner databound control.

Consider the following Example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>

<script runat="server">   
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> TestDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();


        //This is just loading the test dictionary    
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> ColData = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            TestDict.Add("Row Header " + i, ColData);
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                ColData.Add("Col Header " + j, i + j);
            }
        }

        //Bind the Outer Repeater
        RepeaterRow.DataSource = TestDict;
        RepeaterRow.DataBind();



    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterRow" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <%# Eval("Key") %>
                </th>
                <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterColumn" DataSource='<%# Eval("Value")%>' runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Value") %>
                        </td>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```